# Conditional Inner Join using CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to count and sum all of bits column in my table if the sum of it is greater than 2 the `isApprove` column in my `documents` table will be 1.

```
SELECT document_id,
SUM(CASE WHEN isApprove = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS approveBy
FROM approvals_document
```

Output:

```
document_id | approveBy
     96          2
```

I wanted to join the related table for `approvals_document` which is `documents` using this.

```
SELECT document_id, D.isApprove,
SUM(CASE WHEN isApprove = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS approveBy
FROM approvals_document AD
INNER JOIN documents D ON D.id = AD.document_id
```

But it won't join the `isApprove` column. Which part am I missing? Any help would appreciated!

`approvals_document` column

```
id | document_id | isApprove
```

`documents` column

`id | isApprove`

Draft output:

```
document_id | approveBy | isApprove(documents table)

    96           2            0
```

Comment: Will the above work to update the column? Are you sure?

Comment: @AT-2016 In my first query it works. But in my second query it won't join.

Comment: what you mean join the isApprove column? you are joining via document_id try. AD.isApprove, case when AD.isApprove,

Comment: No GROUP BY needed?

Comment: @krishKM I have the same isApprove column in my documents and approvals_document table. I just wanted to select the isApprove column in documents table that's why I used join. You can see that isApprove column in approvals_document I gave an alias on it by approveBy. Please see my updated post.

Comment: @jarlh Yes I can use GROUP BY if needed :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to list all documents and number of approvedBy:

try:

```
SELECT documents.id, 
    documents.isApprove,
    (select count(*) from approvals_document WHERE approvals_document.isApprove =1 and approvals_document.document_id = documents.id) as approveBy
FROM documents;
```

will give you

```
+------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
| documet.id | isapproved or not, | number of times approved |
+------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
|          1 |                  1 |                        2 |
+------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thanks for this. Any tips how can I inject or insert the if condition here?

Comment: @Francisunoxx thats the WHERE approvals_document.isApprove =1 part

Answer (score 3):

Youre missing an equals in the join clause, in the ON, and you need to alias the case:

```
SELECT document_id, D.isApprove,
SUM(CASE WHEN AD.isApprove = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS approveBy
FROM approvals_document AD
INNER JOIN documents D ON D.id = AD.document_id
```

Comment: I just forgot to add the equals in the join clause. It gives me a error ` Column 'isApprove' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: You might need to alias the isApprove inside the case, check my edit

Comment: This gives me a zero value. I have a same column of isApprove in my `approvals_document` and `documents` table. I wanted to select the isApprove in my `documents` table and set a condition to it. I updated my post please see :D

Comment: I've altered my answer to give what you need, I like mine better since there is no inline subquery in the select clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below query using `LEFT JOIN` AND `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT d.id, 
    d.isApprove,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ad.document_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS approveBy
FROM documents d
LEFT JOIN  approvals_document ad
  ON  ad.isApprove =1 and ad.document_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.id,d.isApprove
```